# Why are the checkboxes grayed out when trying to set Program Defaults in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, control-panel

I've been trying to switch my system's default browser away from Pale Moon (a 32 bit browser), and toward Waterfox (x64). However, no matter how I open up the Defaults setting window in the control panel, it won't let me uncheck default boxes that are already checked.

I've tried just manually doing them all at once by clicking "Set this program as default" on Waterfox. After I do that, it says "This program has all the defaults", but when I click on Pale Moon above it, it also says that it has all the defaults.

I can't manually uncheck any of the individual defaults for Pale Moon, nor individually check the defaults for Waterfox. I was able to go into the file-type/protocols default window and individually set the defaults for the .htm/.html files, but when I try to individually set the defaults for the protocols (like HTTP/HTTPS), it only gives me a choices of the 32 bit browsers on my machine (Pale Moon, Chrome, and Internet Explorer). There isn't an option for Waterfox, and there isn't an option to manually select the program from my hard drive.

I'm guessing it has something to do with Windows "wanting" a 32bit program for the browser? Not sure why/how Pale Moon is able to so savagely hold onto those defaults. But after going into Pale Moon's settings and specifically unchecking the "Check to see if I'm default", and then exiting the browser, I still get the behavior.

Google results have still left me stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general Windows wants you to use a 32 bit browser, as far as I know there is no compelling reason to opt for 64 bit. Having said that, if you must use 64 bit, try uninstalling your first browser, rebooting and re-installing your new browser. You may need to right click the icon and choose "Run as an administrator".